# How to solve this error while installing python plugin in eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed.

Session context was:

> (profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>   Unable to read repository at http://pydev.org/updates/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_5.8.0.201706061859.jar.
>
> SSL peer shut down incorrectly
>   Unable to read repository at http://pydev.org/updates/plugins/org.python.pydev.parser.source_5.8.0.201706061859.jar.
>   SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Comment: other eclipse plugins links sometimes not working for me either

Comment: Which Java version do you use? Could you try to add the line `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1` or `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` below the line `-vmargs` in your _eclipse.ini_? If this does not help, try to change the update site URL from _http:..._ to _https:..._ (pydev.org redirects from _http_ to https_).